# How can a DC-DC converter kill SLA battery voltage on light load?

Tags: voltage, batteries, power-electronics

I'm running a small 12V-500V DC-DC converter (shown) on a purely resistive 50mA load.  I was getting weird behavior off my bench 12V DC supply so I plugged in the SLA battery shown.  I connected a multimeter directly to the battery's terminals and read 13V.  It holds that voltage for single-digit mA loads on the high side of the converter, but when I step up to the higher load my high-side ammeter reads 50mA but the battery's voltage collapses.  The multimeter (digital, so only updates a few times per second) shows it mostly hovering about 3.6V, but occasionally cycling to other values from 0 to almost 12V for one update.

[image: SLA and DC-DC converter]

I actually tested two different batteries and got the same behavior.  Then, to make sure it wasn't a surge condition, I put a 3A fuse in-line.  Then, to make sure the batteries weren't just drained, I connected a 4Ω power resistor directly to each one and confirmed no voltage drop and a sustained 3A through the resistor.

These are SLA batteries designed for 120V AC UPS (which can draw 250W for 5-10 minutes), and my high-voltage load that's killing the battery and converter should not be more than 25W.  How is that terminal voltage drop even *possible* given that feeding the converter isn't blowing a 3A fuse and can sustain a direct 3A test?  Evidently there's some dynamic here of which I am ignorant, so what could be going on?

**Amendment:** As another test, to determine if this DC converter has "spikey" demand, I added a 5µF polypropylene capacitor in parallel with the 12V power supply, and put a multimeter on the capacitor's leads.  This eliminated all voltage cycling on the supply side, but it did drop the 12A voltage instantly to just under 6V when load was connected.  Then I put the volt meter on the high side of the DC converter and saw the voltage cycling from 0 to 500V while the high-side ammeter showed it barely holding 50mA.  I could understand high-side problems if the converter were just underrated for the load, but I am still so confused as to how it can affect low-side supply side voltage like that.  Especially with nothing heating up or blowing.

Comment: Further musing: Could this be something like a power-factor problem?

Comment: No. Power factor only applies to AC loads.

Comment: You said you were getting weird behaviour off the bench supply ... what current was it supplying, and what was weird about it?

Comment: SMPS have been known to draw high current as 'pulses' under overload or restart conditions , but that usually blows a fuse, or the SEPIC IC is destroyed.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - I *thought* the bench supply was rated for 10 amps, but even though it never blew a 3A fuse it was also dropping and cycling voltage on non-trivial high-side loads (though not as much as the battery).  It's like something in that power converter is able to drain voltage without pushing current limits.  If I could get any fuses to blow or any component to fail I would understand.  But nothing heats up, nothing bad happens, and even though I've stressed it a bunch of times it continues to function as expected at very low high-side power.

Comment: Hooking a misbehaving converter to a high capacity unregulated battery is a very bad idea.  Perhaps you've got a battery with some protection circuit?  A protection circuit with a much faster response time than your fuse could open the connection, then self-reset (a large fraction of) a second later, and repeat.  A low sample rate multimeter is not going to help diagnose this.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I did have a fuse in line with the battery, and others in the converter and on the high side circuit.  I assume that's adequate protection?  What I was observing from both the bench supply and the battery was essentially fast self-resetting behavior.  Obviously I'm hung up on the fact that this converter and high-side circuit can ghost voltage off the power sources, but if you have any ideas at all for diagnosing or even just illuminating what's going on I'd certainly appreciate them!  (I don't have a scope though....)

Comment: A small (16 to 64 Ohm) speaker or headphone element with a series capacitor 1000 to 10 uF and resistor 100 to 560 Ohm can often be used to 'listen' for audible frequency transient activity when a scope is not available. (Less common now but a crystal earpiece can also be used with just the tip as a test point and the sleeve capacitively loaded with your fingers but only safely in low voltage circuits)

Comment: If your battery is old or otherwise compromised frm overcharging it may exhibit high internal impedance or low capacity that is unable to blow fuses.  Your meter may be misreading pulsed voltages or currents as most (almost all cheap ones) are only fake RMS reading.

Comment: Fuses are relatively slow : you have to wait for the wire to melt. So they won't detect short pulses of high current. Also a bench supply will usually have a "current limit" function you can set to lower levels for additional protection - check it's set where you need it. I'd focus on testing with the PSU first - that may shed light on the battery problem. I'd also test their condition separately, timing a 2A discharge (but not to full capacity)